How to determine if the flow is executed in debug mode from Apex Action
Is it possible to check if a flow is being executed in debug mode from an Apex action that is being called by this flow?
Why do I want that: I want to skip certain actions (e.g. sending out mails) when executing the flow in debug mode.

Did you take a look at Quiddity enum?

yes you can do this.
you can try by creating a custom setting or custom metadata to store the information, you can create  custom setting with fields like FlowName (to identify the flow) and IsDebug  (a Boolean to indicate if the flow is in debug mode).
At the beginning of your flow add an apex action or update Records element to set the IsDebug field of the custom setting based on whether the flow is being run in debug mode. You might set this manually or via some conditions that determine when the flow is considered to be in debug mode.
public class FlowDebugChecker {
public static Boolean isFlowInDebug(String flowName) {
    My_Custom_Setting__c setting = My_Custom_Setting__c.getValues(flowName);
    return (setting != null) ? setting.IsDebug__c : false;
}

}
so whenever you need to check if the flow is in debug mode, call this Apex method.

I would approach this from the opposite direction. Instead of detecting debug mode, check if the flow wants to send an email through a property.
public class MyAction {
  public class Input {
    @InvocableVariable(description='True to send email')
    public Boolean sendEmail;
    // More properties here
  }
  // Whatever results you want to return
  public class Output {
  }
  @InvocableMethod(label='My Action' description='Does some stuff')
  public static Output[] myAction(Input[] inputs) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
    Output[] results = new Output[0];
    for(Input theInput: inputs) {
      Output theResult = new Output();
      if(theInput.sendEmail == true) {
        messages.add(renderEmailFrom(theInput));
      }
      results.add(theResult);
    }
    if(!messages.isEmpty()) {
      Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
    }
  }
  static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage renderEmailFrom(Input theInput) {
    // build and return a message
  }
}

Now, when you're in debug mode, you can just leave the sendEmail property null or false, and when you want to send an email, set it to true.
This design gives you the option to test the action while debugging if you want to, which is arguably better than never sending in debug mode. Also, keep in mind that if you're debugging, as long as the transaction doesn't commit, no email will be sent.
